# Непонятный элемент в DOM

Tags: html

Всем привет! Подскажите пожалуйста! Просматриваю сайт в Firebag, появились какие-то элементы, я отметил на экранном снимке. Из-за этой фигни пляшут все div`ы. Причем это наблюдается на моей рабочей станции, а при копировании на хостинг все нормально отображается. [Ссылка на сайт в сети может поможет](http://testing.ooomercury.com/). Экранный снимок - на нем все показано.

[image]

Comment: неприятный коричневый цвет, нечитабельный хидер, ведущие в никуда ссылки в меню, фиксированное разрешение...а вы из-за съехавших дивов волнуетесь=)

Comment: Коричневый цвет как бы намекает нам из чего сделан сайтик... :-D

Comment: @BETEP, на этом ресурсе ваше пребывание только что кончилось.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас проблемы внутри файлов шаблонов. Этот символ - это [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) в переводе на HTML сущность. Удалите BOM в ваших шаблонах и всё будет ОК.

Comment: Ооо великий! Благодарю :) Действительно перекодировал в UTF-8 без BOM и все стало отлично :)